# Need help understanding why IPython kernel keeps dying when running CNN on GPU

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying my hand at training off MNIST data using Keras to make a 2D convolutional neural network. Im using Anaconda, with python 3.5.0, 64bit. Just installed the GPU version of tensorflow and ran

`from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()`

to get `[name: "/cpu:0"
 device_type: "CPU"
 memory_limit: 268435456
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 319475955830947664, name: "/gpu:0"
 device_type: "GPU"
 memory_limit: 3282324684
 locality {
   bus_id: 1
 }
 incarnation: 17748449796282282037
 physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 960M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0"]`

It successfully trained on a simple fully connected neural network, but the kernel dies and restarts whenever I try to fit the CNN. The issue doesn't arise when using the CPU.

Comment: isn`t related to your memory,reduce batch size when fitting...if you can save your model after training...kill the cpu process to release memory with kill -9 process number and fit with the saved model

Comment: Is there any error message from the kernel as it dies? This could help debug whether it's a memory issue, a cuda driver issue, or something else entirely.